# Google maps LatLngBounds doesn't work sometimes with a javascript object

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, bounds

I have a problem with my map. I'm using the google maps funtion `LatLngBounds()` in order to calculate the center between two given points.

I'm able to get the location and I consoled.log the value (even if, for some reason the values are empty, I'm still able to print them to the map) so I'm able to place my markers on the map, but for some reason, when I add the function for the bound, I break the map, I get an error and I'm only able to see a marker (one marker.

Here's my code:

```
var locs;

function initMap() {

  var locations_two = [
    ['<div class=""><p>Vancouver</p></div>', 49.27597, -123.1185, 1],
    ['<div class=""><p>Ottawa</p></div>', 45.3683, -75.70258]
  ];

  locs = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('locs'), {
    center: {lat: 49.276873, lng: -123.118948},
    zoom: 4
  });

  var image = $myimage;

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker_two, i;

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (i = 0; i < locations_two.length; i++) {
    var mybond = locations_two[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mybond[1], mybond[2]);
    marker_two = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: locs,
        icon: image
    });
    bounds.extend(myLatLng);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker_two, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations_two[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker_two, i));
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }

}
```

As I said, I declared the variable `var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();` before the loop and then I use the two other google map function in order to call the `map.fitBounds(bounds);` at the very end, to center my map but I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'fitBounds' of undefined

Which doesn't make sense for me because the bounds variable is actually defined? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the posted code I get a javascript error (in Chrome):

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: map is not defined

Your `google.maps.Map` object is named `locs`, not `map`. This line:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

should be:

```
locs.fitBounds(bounds);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tpzreL38/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var locs;

function initMap() {
  var locations_two = [
    ['<div class=""><p>Vancouver</p></div>', 49.27597, -123.1185, 1],
    ['<div class=""><p>Ottawa</p></div>', 45.3683, -75.70258]
  ];
  locs = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('locs'), {
    center: {
      lat: 49.276873,
      lng: -123.118948
    },
    zoom: 4
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker_two, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (i = 0; i < locations_two.length; i++) {
    var mybond = locations_two[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mybond[1], mybond[2]);
    marker_two = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: locs,
    });
    bounds.extend(myLatLng);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker_two, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations_two[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker_two, i));
    locs.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#locs {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="locs"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```